# How to zoom into webpages/images using my touchpad?

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 and I cant really zoom into webpages and images anymore, previously in Windows 10 it was seamless and zooming into webpages was very similar as zooming into them using a mobile, can anyone help me out with this?
I'm using Asus Vivobook 15 509DA-EJ741T

Answer (score 2):

I’ve got an Asus Zenbook - to zoom in on web pages I slide 2 fingers down the touchpad whilst holding down ctrl (and slide up with ctrl pressed to zoom out). Hope that works for you!

Comment: And for what it's worth, I too transitioned not so long ago from Win 10 to Ubuntu and haven't looked back. The only thing I haven't been able to do is find a way to do what iTunes does (ie sync music on iPhone) but for everything else there's something that works at least as well, and often better. I hope you find it as rewarding as I did.

Comment: Works for me in XFCE (Xubuntu). Did not know that this feature even existed. Thank you.